# Native app for Android and iOS. Little Javascript knowledge. NativeScript? ReactNative? Other ideas?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, nativescript

I need to develop a native app for both OS.
This would be a simple app, not too complex.

What would you recommend for me to use? I only have little Javascript knowledge. Don't know anything about React or other frameworks.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Two other questions seem to be relevant to giving proper guidance.  1) Do you also need a web application with this same functionality?  2) Is a PWA an option, to give mobile-like experience without a true native app? https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend NativScript if you know JavaScript as for Flutter you need to learn Dart.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695403/nativescript-vs-flutter/52695705#52695705) is the comparison I posted for NativeScript and Flutter.

I use Nativescript with Angular but you can use plain JS as well.
Another reason to use Nativescript is theier [marketplace](https://market.nativescript.org/) and if you use some pre-built plugins, the time for building of NativeScript applications will be decreased

Comment: One thing I love about NativeScript is the unlimited access to native apis using just JavaScript, where with Flutter / ReactNative you will still have to write a plugin in native language (Objective C / Java) and bridge it to Dart / JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Hence you are Looking to develop application for both **android** and **ios** with **java script**

***You could use following tools / frameworks***

- [phone gap](https://phonegap.com/)

**as and option you could use**

- [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)

these could be best if you don't prefer react native or native script

**else if you are okay with angular and jquery then**

- [mobile angular](http://mobileangularui.com/)
- [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)

also you can drag and drop themes with [ThemeRoller jQuery Mobile](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/)

these above mentioned tools / frameworks has huge amount of tutorial in you tube and other blogs (my personal choice would be ionic / phonegap)

**NOTE:**
**phone gap free for personal use
**others are completely free

Answer (score 0):

For both OS, i would recommend `Flutter`, open source mobile application SDK developed by google.

- Flutter is Google’s mobile app SDK for crafting high-quality native
  interfaces on iOS and Android in record time. Flutter works with
  existing code, is used by developers and organizations around the
  world, and is free and open source.

For more information on flutter ,see [flutter.io](https://flutter.io/)

For flutter examples   [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Flutter)